# On Homepage "is_user_logged_in()" function is not working after login and it is working after refresh the page?

Tags: login

I'm trying to add the menu items using filter.

Below is the full function

```
function new_nav_menu_items($items) {
    
    $loginLink = '<li id="menu-item-login" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="'.wp_login_url().'">Login</a></li>';
    
    $resgisterLink = '<li id="menu-item-register" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom  top-menu-signup"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Subscribe</a></li>';
    
    // add the home link to the end of the menu

    if(is_user_logged_in())
    {

        global $current_user; 
        wp_get_current_user();
        //$current_user->ID;

        $user_firstname =get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'first_name', true);

        $user_lastname =get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'last_name', true);
        
        $editProfile = '<li id="menu-item-119" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-119 user-name"><a class="user-name-menu" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="icon-admin-user"></i>'.$user_firstname.' '.$user_lastname.'</a>
        <ul class="sub-user-menu">
            <li><a href="'.home_url('edit-profile').'"><i class="icon-edit"></i>Edit Profile</a></li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><a href="'.wp_logout_url().'"><i class="icon-logout"></i>Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>';
        
        $items = $items. $editProfile;
    }
    else
    {
        $items = $items . $loginLink . $resgisterLink;
    }
    
    return $items;
}
// to handle login/logout links on the home page header menu

add_action( 'init', 'nothing_register_menus' );

function nothing_register_menus()
{
    is_user_logged_in();
    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items', 10, 2 );
}
```

After login, "is_user_logged_in()" is always false, but after refresh the page in login state it shows login correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no condition inside "nothing_register_menus". It executes first `is_user_logged_in();` and then the filter. No matter what.

It seems that it should execute the filter IFF is_user_logged_in is TRUE.

Also maybe consider a redirection to home page after log in that might trigger it, or some other AJAX workaround.

^^